# How to remove the line in the dialog box?

Tags: android, android-dialog, dialog

Hi i am creating one custom dialog box. It display some list of files using listview. In My dialog box does not fit the line. For example i mentioned the Red Color in the dialog box. How to remove this line or fit with this line.

[image]

Thanks. My Another ScreenShot is
[image]

How to Remove Space int the ( Red mark ) and how to add space in the ( green Mark, because it's look loke not good ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `android:divider="@android:color/transparent"` in your `xml ListView` declaration.

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. I got a solution. I need additional information. Please read my question.

Comment: For red mark: do changes in the layout of your layout for dialog and for green mark you can use android:dividerHeight.

Comment: Sorry. I can't understand. Please explain me. Where do may i put the code.